# Open application on notification click in OneSignal

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

I am getting notification using this through `OneSignal`, but I want to open the application when I click on notification

```
private static class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
    @Override
    public void notificationOpened(String message, JSONObject additionalData, boolean isActive) {

        try {
            if (additionalData != null) {
                if (additionalData.has("actionSelected"))
                    Log.d("OneSignalExample", "OneSignal notification button with id " + additionalData.getString("actionSelected") + " pressed");
                Log.d("OneSignalExample", "Full additionalData:\n" + additionalData.toString());
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

Add a constructor in `ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler` that takes context as a parameter

```
private Context mContext;

public ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

Init `OneSignal` with `ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler` constructor with context inside application class

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    OneSignal.startInit(this)
             .setNotificationOpenedHandler((OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler)
                        new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler(this))
             .init();
}
```

Prepare intent and start your activity using context

```
@Override
public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
    try {
        if (additionalData != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailsActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("key", <additionalData to be sent>);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your OneSignalPushApplication class, initialize:

```
OneSignal.startInit(this)
          .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())
          .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
          .autoPromptLocation(true)
          .init();
```

and declare ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler as:

```
private class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
          // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it.
          @Override
          public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {

         String title=result.notification.payload.title;
         String desc=result.notification.payload.body;

         Log.d("xiomi", "Received Title "+title);
         Log.d("xiomi", "Received Desc "+desc);


             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourMainActivity.class);
             intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
             intent.putExtra("push_title", title);
             intent.putExtra("push_message", desc);
             startActivity(intent);          

      }
   }
```