# OneSignal - notification not opening my app

Tags: java, android, onesignal

I can't open my app by clicking on a notification in OneSignal if the app is closed.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

public class Loader extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String ONESIGNAL_APP_ID = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx";//my app id instead of "xxxx"

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Enable verbose OneSignal logging to debug issues if needed.
        OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE);

        // OneSignal Initialization
        OneSignal.initWithContext(this);
        OneSignal.setAppId(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID);
    }
}
```

manifest contains:

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT"
     android:value="DISABLE" 
/>
```

Gradle files like in onesignal sdk setup tutorial https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup

Comment: If you connect OneSignal in an older way, then everything works. Code in onCreate :
`OneSignal.startInit(this).inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification).unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true).init();`
OneSignal version 3.11.2 instead of 4.0.0 in build.gradle

Comment: Hi! Have you had the chance to test this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997419/open-application-on-notification-click-in-onesignal